# Welcome page doesn't disappear after timeout

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage, settimeout

## The welcome page should ONLY appear during the first visit to the site

Accordingly, I used the useEffect hook, inside it I define the LocalStorage constant. I also use setTimeout to make the greeting disappear after a certain amount of time.

```
const [showStartPage, setShowStartPage] = useState(startPage.nothingShow);

    useEffect(() => {
        const firstTimeLoaded = localStorage.getItem("firstTimeLoaded")
        if (!firstTimeLoaded) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                setShowStartPage(startPage.startPageShow);
                localStorage.setItem("firstTimeLoaded", "true");
            }, 2500);
        } else setShowStartPage(startPage.startPageNotShow)
    }, []);
```

```
<Fragment>
    <Stack>
       CONTENT ==>
    </Stack>
    {showStartPage === 2 && (<StartPage />)}
</Fragment>
```

==> Here is the content that is located under the welcome page during the first visit to the site.

To determine the state of the welcome page, I use an enum that includes 3 states:

1. when the welcome page is shown
2. when the welcome page is not shown
3. when the state is not yet defined

```
export enum startPage {
    startPageShow = 2,
    startPageNotShow = 1,
    nothingShow = 0
}
```

**As a result, the welcome page is not loaded when you re-enter the site, as it should be. Loads the first time you visit the site, as it should be. But it does not disappear after a while, as it should NOT.**

What did I do wrong?

I tried to simplify the situation by excluding the enum and leaving only boolean values, but I need an undefined state to not show anything until the state is defined

Answer (score 1):

```
useEffect(() => {
        const firstTimeLoaded = localStorage.getItem("firstTimeLoaded");
        if (!firstTimeLoaded) {
            setShowStartPage(startPage.startPageShow); // appear
            setTimeout(() => {
                setShowStartPage(startPage.startPageNotShow); // after 2500ms disappear
                localStorage.setItem("firstTimeLoaded", "true"); 
            }, 2500);
        } else setShowStartPage(startPage.startPageNotShow)
    }, []);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm stuck at this moment, I don't even know why, maybe it's the lack of electricity. Now everything works as it should, thank you very much again

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [initializer function](https://initializer%20function) to get the `showStartPage` state from local storage. If the key doesn't exist in local storage (or `false`), show the start page, and trigger the `setTimeout` in the `useEffect` to hide it.

```
// init state from local storage using an initializer function
const [showStartPage, setShowStartPage] = useState(() => !JSON.parse(localStorage.get('firstTimeLoaded') ?? 'false'));

useEffect(() => {
  if(showStartPage) { // if the state page is displayed
    setTimeout(() => { // hide it after a timeout and set storage
      localStorage.setItem('firstTimeLoaded', true);
      setShowStartPage(false);
    }, 2500);  
  }
}, [showStartPage]);

return (
  <Fragment>
    // ...content
    {showStartPage && (<StartPage />)}
  </Fragment>
);
```